# Could not load file or assembly - The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

Tags: .net, windows

On only one specific workstation, running a .NET assembly using the System.Configuration .dll fails with this error referencing

System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

It reproduces 100% where the following code is all that's being run, and it reproduces using x86, x64, AnyCPU, Framework 4, Framework 4 client profile, and Framework  4.6.2.  Its a fresh install of Windows 10 Home, reloaded twice with the same problem.  Trying to install any .NET framework says its included with the OS.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Install .net runtime 4.5, that's where my version of that dll is coming from:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Configuration.dll

'Client profile' is very trimmed down and misses some things that devs consider basic.

Alternatively, if that's the only machine that's affected, you could copy the dll from a working machine into the same folder as the exe. Pure heresy, but does work :P

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback!  Unfortunately every version of .NET I try to install, including 4.5 just now, comes back saying its already part of the OS.  Also, The GAC only has version 2 for this .dll, but a working workstation only has version 2 also.

Comment: I did a little more digging and found "So if your application is incompatible with .NET 4.6 and later you will need to update your application." which I naturally see as more a challenge than a hurdle ;)

Comment: Yeah I think this must be machine-specific; that 2-line app fails even when its compiled against 4.6

Comment: Maybe check the windows features. I don't see 4.0 or 4.5 in my feature list, but it should be in there somewhere.